# Virtual Classes Multiple Inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface, virtual

I have this following scenario:

```
class RenderObject {
  public:
    virtual void sendToGPU() = 0;
    virtual void removeFromGPU() = 0;
};

class Object3D : public RenderObject {
  public:
    virtual char getType() = 0;
};

class IGroup : public RenderObject {
  public:
    void sendToGPU(); // implementation of RenderObject's virtual method
    void removeFromGPU(); // implementation of RenderObject's virtual method
};

class Group : public Object3D, public IGroup {
  public:
    char getType(); // implementation of Object3D's virtual method
};
```

And the Group class is inheriting RenderObject twice. I know it is a common problem in multiple inheritance, but I really don't know how to solve it, since it is the first time I face it. Even knowing it is a common problem, I couldn't find a solution that considers the previous implementation in one of the parents (IGroup).

A solution with an explanation how this language mechanics works would be appreciated.

Comment: search `virtual inheritance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object3D and IGroup need to virtually inherit:

```
class Object3D : virtual public RenderObject
```

[IBM C++: Virtual Base Class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr135.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example for the need for virtual inheritance.

By providing the `virtual` keyword, you eliminate the ambiguous hierarchy problem.

Change your code to:

```
class Object3D : public virtual RenderObject {
  public:
    virtual char getType() = 0;
};

class IGroup : public virtual RenderObject {
  public:
    void sendToGPU(); // implementation of RenderObject's virtual method
    void removeFromGPU(); // implementation of RenderObject's virtual method
};
```

Check the following link for more information:

[Virtual Inheritance Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)